# What is Keyable is Guidewire Policy Center?

Tags: guidewire, gosu

What is Keyable in Guidewire PolicyCenter?
Is it related to entities?
How can we create this Keyable enities in Guidewire PolicyCenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyable is a type of entity in GW. According to documentation:

> A keyable entity that has an ID, but it is not editable. It is possible to delete entities of this type from the database. Guidewire recommends that you do not use this entity type. Use versionable instead.

When you create a new entity you can select type as you can see below.
[image]